# Wrapping multiple lines of text around inline image

Tags: react-native

In react-native, I have found topics that say to put `<Image>` inline, however they want an inline image the same size. I am trying to wrap multiple lines. I used this code and demo - https://snack.expo.dev/@noitidart/wrap-multiple-lines-around-image

```
import React from 'react';
import { Image, Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>
        <Image
          source={{ uri: 'https://via.placeholder.com/100' }}
          style={{
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
          }}
        />
        <Text style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          This is long text it should wrap around the image. Lorem ipsum even
          more haha that's kind of cool. Is this working? It is but it's only keeping the first line of text and then the second line and on are on top of the image.
        </Text>
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

However only the first line respects the width of the image left. Here is a screenshot, does anyone know how to make multiple lines wrap?

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution to this after all?

Comment: @NikitasIO no I didn't. :( I'm still looking, please share if you discover something.

Comment: It seems to me that this is not currently possible in React Native. I've looked for a solution that works on Android and I could not find anything. There don't seem to be any npm packages for this either.

But maybe you could put a bounty on this and for the best... You have more than enough reputation points.

Comment: I recall react-native-skia has a solution for this. Or they are working on a solution. But I think the image has to be rendered in Skia as well. If you try that direction it would be awesome to see your investigation.

Answer (score -1):

To achieve the desired layout where text wraps around the image,

you can use the **ImageBackground** component with appropriate styling.

for example

```
 <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
  <ImageBackground
    source={{ uri: 'url' }}
    style={{
      width: 100,
      height: 100
    }}>
    <Text></Text>
  </ImageBackground>
  <Text style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    text content
  </Text>
</View>
```

Comment: This doesn't work, I tried your code - https://i.imgur.com/SLCMq2S.png - notice how there is now a wall of text to the right of the `<ImageBackground>` - it's not wrapping around.