# How to wrap text around image in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, image, text

So, I have a bunch of text in normal format and a photo that I want the text to wrap around. I did some searches and they said to put the image element in the text element. Like wise:

```
<Text>
      <Image />
      Random Text to wrap around
</Text>
```

This works... kind of...[example of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkaPb.png)
But as you can see, for some reason the text doesn't start all the way at the top. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to float text around image in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39514335/how-to-float-text-around-image-in-react-native)

Comment: A newer one: [Wrapping multiple lines of text around inline image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69216957/wrapping-multiple-lines-of-text-around-inline-image) Apparently it's a challenge still.

Comment: `<View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "flex-start", flexDirection: "row" }}>
        <Image
          style={{
            width: 50,
            height: 50,
          }}
          source={require("@expo/snack-static/react-native-logo.png")}
        />
        <Text style={{ paddingHorizontal: 5 }}>
          Your past has been in control for far too long. It's time to shift to
          a higher expression of what you are capable of so you can create the
          life you want to live.
        </Text>
      </View>`